# Freelance on tourist visa in Australia

Tags: legal

Hi I have been trying to seek for a specific answer, I hope anyone can help.I am a Filipino Citizen and will visit in Australia this September 2016-April 2017 for the 2nd time. My boyfriend will sponsor me. I just got hired as a virtual assistant,my job is only email response!My clients are Australian but Singapore based. My payment is sent to my Philippines bank account in Philippines currency.During the 6 months I will be in Australia my salary will be sent my Philippines account. I wont even bring my bank card with me when I travel. Can I still work? Please help.I will migrate to Australia in September 2017.Thank you!

Comment: I think this is *far more* an immigration and legal question than it is a freelance question. You may not get any answers here. You *might* try http://law.stackexchange.com but I'm just speculating.

Comment: what visa do you have?

Answer (score 2):

As long as your online work is incidental to your travel in Australia, then there should be no conflict with your visa. But technically, if you're working full-time, you might have an issue with one clause.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18076/does-condition-8115-mean-you-cant-check-your-work-email/18077

In reality, you're not doing an Australian job, or doing an Aussie out of a potential job... So there's probably no issue...  but those of us who have our own businesses and stay in foreign countries for long periods, the water does get a little muddy.

Ingat!